# Creating a dictionary of all prefixes of a string in Python

Tags: python, strings, hash-map

```
a=raw_input()
prefix_dict = {}
for j in xrange(1,len(a)+1):
    prefix = a[:j]
    prefix_dict[prefix] = len(prefix)
print prefix_dict
```

Is there any possibility of memory error in the above code?

Comment: A memory error? Please explain.

Comment: @JoelCornett The above code is a part of another code from a contest. when tried on the website it gave a memoryerroer at `prefix = a[:j]
`.

Comment: Oh, I see. What implementation of python are you using?

Comment: @JoelCornett Sorry, but I lost you "What implementation of python are you using?" do u mean version or anything else??

Comment: I mean, what are you running this code on? cPython? Jython? Stackless Python? The code as given shouldn't give you an error, so any errors would be platform specific. Are you sending this code to a server?

Comment: @JoelCornett On my system its not giving any error but on the server of the website its giving an error, the server is a quad core Xeon machines running 32-bit Ubuntu (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).For few cases its working and for few its showing memory error. FYI: I do not know the cases that they are testing but inputs are lower case alphabets.

Comment: I suggest that you put this question on stackoverflow.com. You'll get an answer to your question more quickly that way.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what is making the error occur without giving us the input, but it's certainly possible the input is too large for the system to store.

`prefix_dict` will contain `len(a)` entries so if your input is larger than 32-bit python allows for dictionary size on your machine, then that could be the issue.

I will note that instead of having `prefix_dict[prefix] = len(prefix)` you could just have `prefix_dict[prefix] = j` which would stop you from needing to do an extra length calculation each time (not that this would be the cause of the memory issue).

Take a look at the sample output (I modified the print statement and used an example string):

```
>>> prefix_dict = {}
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> for j in xrange(1,len(a)+1):
        prefix = a[:j]
        prefix_dict[prefix] = len(prefix)
        print j, len(prefix), prefix_dict

1 1 {'h': 1}
2 2 {'h': 1, 'he': 2}
3 3 {'hel': 3, 'h': 1, 'he': 2}
4 4 {'hel': 3, 'h': 1, 'hell': 4, 'he': 2}
5 5 {'hel': 3, 'h': 1, 'hell': 4, 'hello': 5, 'he': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The slice operator in `a[:j]` creates a copy of the sublist so is perfectly possible that you get a MemoryError.